# Adding a border to input with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a website with a complex CSS file. I have added a new feature, but I can't seem to edit an input tab that I have due to other styling affecting it. Essentially I am trying to over-ride a certain property.

**CSS**

```
textarea, input[type="number"]{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0 solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035) inset;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}


select, input[type="number"] {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    color: #555555;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 37px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

select, textarea, input[type="number"]
    color: #626c72;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    width: 100%;
}

.target {
    border: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="Label1">Label1:</label>
                <input class="form-control target"  step="any" type="number" min="0" max="24"></input> 
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is have is override `border: 0 solid #CCCCCC;` from the first selector and make it look like the default bootstrap input for the `.target` input . I don't want it to affect all other inputs in my application. I only want it to affect the html you see above. I thought my last styling `.target` selector would do the trick, but it doesn't. My jsFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/or6brfbm/2/). I want the default bootstrap border/outline for my input. As you can tell its not there right now.

Comment: The input already has `0` border from the `textarea, input[type="number"]textarea, input[type="number"]` rules.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You said you were trying to override a style with the `.target` style you have at the bottom, but that style of `border:0` is already being applied by the `input` selector. There's no difference between `border: 0 solid #CCCCCC;` and `border:0;` so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want the default bootstrap outline/border for inputs to be applied to this element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS [:not selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) if you don't want your custom CSS to apply to that specific input:

```
textarea, input[type="number"]:not(.target) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0 solid #CCCCCC;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035) inset;
    transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}


select, input[type="number"]:not(.target) {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    color: #555555;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 37px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 2px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

## [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xeNr6rVMvO)

Comment: Because there's no difference between that and the style you are already applying to the input. `border:0` means no border.

Comment: So the only way to do this leveraging my `.target` selector is to add properties that emulate the bootstrap input styling?

Comment: No, there are many ways to do it, this answer I provided is one of those ways.

Comment: Is there a simple way do to it via using a CSS selector that selects `.target`? If so, could you show that? Or do you think your method is a best practice? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, this answer does exactly that. Have you looked at my answer yet or are you just commenting?

Comment: What I mean is there a way to use `.target { styling here }` to achieve the same result as opposed to the :not selector.

Comment: Yes, by copying all of bootstraps input styling into that selector, but using the :not selector is best practice

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
 input.target {
    border: 0;
 }
```

or

```
 input[type="number"].target {
    border: 0;
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I want this element to look like the default bootstrap input.

Comment: Oh! ok in this case it's pseudo selector `:not` which is useful like you see in the previous answer